# Populate Various Comboboxes by Function Call

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Morning !

I'm trying to make my code more generic by using Functions to populate various ComboBoxes, however, I'm with troubles to do this...

In UserForm:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    
    Call Lista_Vendedores
    ComboBox1.List = Lista_Vendedores    
End Sub
```

In Module:

```
Public Function Lista_Vendedores() As Variant

Dim Lista As New Collection
Dim Cont_Vendedores As Integer

Cont_Vendedores = Plan1.Cells(1, 8).Value

Sheets("Plan1").Select

For i = 3 To Cont
    Lista (Row.Cells(i, 8))
    MsgBox Lista
Next i 

Set Lista_Vendedores = Lista
Set Lista = Nothing    

End Function
```

When I try to run the code, nothing happens, however, none error is shown.

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be simplified a lot. It doesn't need to be in a function, just give it a range as per the example below:

Userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A8")
End Sub
```

Module:

```
Public Sub ShowUserform()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your support !

Comment: FWIW - For the OP's use the line (which you correctly state to be an example only) will need to be `ComboBox1.List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Range("H3:H" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Plan1").Range("H1").Value)`.  (Assuming I have interpreted the original question correctly, which is always a dangerous assumption.)

Answer (score 2):

You are making lots of mistakes in your code, and while CallumDA33 solution is better, I think you should take a look at this:

First, you are not calling your function correctly. The sub should be:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()    
    ComboBox1.List = Lista_Vendedores    
End Sub
```

The `Call` line is not necessary. (and the keyword `Call` itself is almost never required). I really don't get where your syntax is coming from.

- In the `Lista_Vendedores` function, you are not using correctly the `Lista`  `Collection`.
- `Cont` is undefined. You should always use `Option Explicit` at the start of your modules.
- You are not affecting any value to the collection.
- You should also avoid using `Select` as much as possible.
- The `List` property expect an variant array, not a collection, so the function should return a variant array, not an variant containing a single (empty) collection object, so I also changed the type for Lista.

Follows corrected but untested code:

```
Public Function Lista_Vendedores() As Variant()   

    Dim Lista As Variant()
    Dim Cont_Vendedores As Integer

    With Sheets("Plan1")

        Cont_Vendedores = .Cells(1, 8).Value
        Redim Lista(0 to Cont_Vendedores-3)

        For i = 3 To Cont_Vendedores
            Lista(i-3) = .Cells(i,8)
        Next i 
    End With

    Lista_Vendedores = Lista
End Function
```

Edit: corrected typo

Comment: Vicent G, it was amazing ! I know I'm making lots of mistakes. First of all, I was doing this kind of programming as long as I need, in as many userforms and combobox appears, but it start to became a dumb way. Doing like his I make my code more general and clear. You Do help me ! I tested and it works, thank you !

Comment: @VincentG there's a `Cont_VendedoresLista` that is very likely to be `Cont_Vendedores`...

Comment: I used Con_Vendedores and it works properly ! Thank you @user3598756

Comment: @FernandaAline, you are welcome but it was just a typo: accept VincentG answer!